# How do I stop my files appearing at the desktop on windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, desktop

Recently I've noticed that the files in my Desktop Section (within file explorer) are beginning to appear on the main desktop, which didn't happen before. It's beginning to annoy me as I have lots of files so my desktop is beginning to look like a mess. Is there anyway I can prevent data within the Desktop folder to not actually appear on the Desktop Screen?

Comment: Are you sure it didn't happen before? As far as I know, this is the default behavior.

Comment: Files in the desktop folder are going to appear on the desktop, this has always been the case, if you don't want files to appear on the desktop don't put them in that folder.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, there is a program that writes those files. Look for the program.